# Proof center of subgroup equal to intersection with center of group

Tags: group-theory

Recently one of my teacher has given me this question:

If $G$ is a group, is it true that $Z(G) = \{1\} $ and $H \leq G$ then $Z(H) = \{1\}$? If false give a counterexample, if true prove it.

In this
[site](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_whose_center_is_contained_in_the_center_of_the_whole_group), I've found equivalent conditions to denote the center of a subgroup. The second equivalence condition states $Z(H) = Z(G) \cap H$. From it the solution is quite clear, but how can I prove this equality? Why can I state with certainty that it does not exist $h \in C_G(H) \cap H$, $h \notin Z(G)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think about the simplest subgroup you can find containing $g(\neq 1)\in G$ and consider what you know about that.

Comment: Excelent hint/example. +1 Perhaps I'd only add "the simplest group **with trivial center...**"

Comment: Got it, all elements in $\left < g \right >$ commute with each other, since they are all powers of g. Thus when $H = \left < g \right >$, $Z(H) = H$, since H is abelian.